# Kaspersky Virus Definitions Update to Another Computer

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, kaspersky

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Kaspersky Virus Definitions Update to Another Computer](https://superuser.com/questions/214528/move-kaspersky-virus-definitions-update-to-another-computer)

I want to copy Kaspersky updates that are available from another computer to mine. How can I copy the update files?  Is it possible to do so?  Which update files should I copy?

Answer (score 0):

check [Kaspersky Distribution Update](http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2012/settings/update?qid=208284398)

Pretty Simple Really