# How to copy Kaspersky 2013 virus definitions update to another computer?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, updates, kaspersky

I have 5 computers and installed the same anti-virus (Kaspersky Internet Security 2013) on all of them. Now I want to update the anti-virus on the computers. Since my bandwidth and time are limited, I was wondering if there's a way to download the updates on just one computer and then copy it to the others. This way I wouldn't need to download the same updates on all five computers.

I found an [older question on the same subject](https://superuser.com/questions/214528/move-kaspersky-virus-definitions-update-to-another-computer), but the answer is not possible anymore with the 2013 version. I also found [this Kaspersky support article](http://support.kaspersky.com/6385), but the "Copy update to folder" option is not showing in Kaspersky 2013.

Any other ways to do this? All computers are running Windows.

Comment: Does this article help : [How to Update Kaspersky Antivirus Offline ?](http://www.tricksmachine.com/2009/03/how-to-update-kaspersky-antivirus-offline.html), which describes using the unsupported Kaspersky Update utility.

Comment: @harrymc it is for how to download virus-definition offline. This will help, when i haven't downloaded definition using Kaspersky. But, my question is, if i have already downloaded virus definition through Kaspersky, those definition can i use to other computer. ??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Kaspersky removed this option from Antivirus and Internet Security suites from 2013 version.
The "Copy updates to folder" option is currently available in Kaspersky Pure 2.0.

The `%appdata%` options may work but not a guaranteed way to do it.
Right now, using the updater utility seems to be your only option.
http://support.kaspersky.com/updater#

Comment: Updater are only helpful, when you want to download virus-definition without using Kaspersky. I mean, it like, it will make the separate folder of virus-definition, which i can use every where. But, scenario is something different here. I have already downloaded virus-definition and  i don't want to waste my bandwidth anymore. So, i just wanna re-use same definition to for other computers.

Comment: well....what you can do is download updates to a shared location using updater and update ALL PCs from there....that way, you effectively download updates only once...yes, it will involve huge download for the first time but i don't see any other option

Answer (score 0):

Warning: The following is pure conjecture and might not work, as I am not a user of Kaspersky.

The first entry in [this thread](http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=968) contains the old placement of definition files:

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Kaspersky Lab\KAV for Workstations\5.0\Bases`

You could find its equivalent for Kaspersky 2013 and your Windows version. Then compare contents on both computers, and if they are different try to copy from new to old.

Save the old contents of this folder in case this procedure kills Kaspersky, for example by renaming the "Bases" folder to "Bases.old".

You will also need to disable Kaspersky on the computer you are copying-to during this operation. Also be ready for the possibility that you will need to reinstall Kaspersky if things go real bad.

For another method using the unsupported Kaspersky Update utility, see this article :
[Create Kaspersky Update Server Mirror for Offline Updates](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-kaspersky-update-server-mirror-for-offline-updates/).

Comment: I even tried the 1st method, as they mentioned in one article that, updates are stored in AppData folder. So, i tried to copy the updates into that location. But, when i started kaspersky to  update. Then, it say, virus-definition is corrupted and it start downloading from the very first. :(
And, bout the second method. It is same as you have mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Well, if you don't like the second method, and unless someone else comes up with a better answer, then you will need to find the answer the detective way : Take a Kaspersky installation, update the definitions and find out which files have changed. You could use for that a utility such as [FileLocator Lite](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=filelocatorlite&page=home) to search for files newer-than.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Kaspersky Lab\AVP12\Update distribution

when you go to (all users) just go to tools/folder options/view then mark show hiden folder and files you will see Application Data

follow the top in formation

Comment: I won't be helpful. Because, possibly i could miss some file their and that will lead to definition corruption, as I have already faced this problem

Answer (score 0):

Anti-virus companies eventually take away this ability and create a 'server-class' product/feature.  In Kaspersky's case- [this](http://www.kaspersky.com/endpoint-security-windows#ca).  The page references several business-class products that have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it using kaspersky update utility. See this link: [How to update kaspersky antivirus and internet security 2013 offline](http://www.tipsdrive.com/2013/03/how-to-update-kaspersky-antivirus-internet-security-2013-offline.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install KIS 2012. When you update it, tick the copy of distribution box in update settings. When you finish, copy the update distribution to any folder / drive. Uninstall KIS 2013, then restart.

Once you finish, install KIS 2013 again, and update with the update distribution you have copied before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the updater and tick the "use local bases if possible" checkbox

and  create a temp folder in your updater folder

and copy the tempfolder of your Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 product to temp folder of updater utility

by these settings the updater utility will use your downloaded temp files and add the new ones to them 
http://support.kaspersky.com/5273

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky Offline Update files can be downloaded with the Kaspersky Update Utility not by others.... For that go to this link:

http://support.kaspersky.com/updater2#downloads

The new version kaspesky update works for the old kaspersky too...
And you can distribute these update files as you like always...